# Run x11vnc on boot with LightDM

Tags: gentoo, x11vnc, lightdm

I use Gentoo. I'm fighting with one problem - how to startup x11vnc server with lightdm. I have i3wm installed with LightDM, everything is configured and works, but the only problem is remaining - I cannot start x11vnc properly. It complains that it can't open display :0. I've tried many ways:

1. Tried to change depends() function in x11vnc init-script, (changed "need xdm" to "after xdm") - doesn't work
2. Tried to use VNCServer section in the lightdm configuration file. (changed "enabled" to true and replaced the "command" with "rc-service x11vnc re-/start") - doesn't work
3. Tried to use display-setup-script just to try to run x11vnc after the lightdm will run X. Also I tried to use greeter-setup-script. Both are don't work :(
4. Tried to use for-loop in start() function of x11vnc init-script just to wait for X will launch. Doesn't work

Why am I still trying to find a way to launch it? Because if I wait for LightDM will start (while greeter will appear) and switch to another terminal and launch x11vnc manually - it works! So please help me to fix it, thanks in advance!